# How to create a loop for subtraction in MATLAB for arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, while-loop

I'm new to MATLAB and want to learn more about looping. First, I have an array called "A":

```
A = 4 
    6
    7
    11
    12 
    17
    22
    25
```

Next, I want to create an array that will subtract each row. So, it would essentially do "6-4", "7-6", "11-7", "12-11", "17-12", "22-17", "25-22". I want this to be displayed as:

```
2
1
3
1
5
5
3
```

However, what I have doesn't output anything.

I tried using a "while" loop but I don't receive any output, no error message either. What I have so far is shown below:
PS - I have used Python before so maybe I am mixing up Python syntax with MATLAB or maybe my logic is wrong ?

```
B = length(A); %will output the length of A, which is 8

while i <= B
    X = A(i, 1); %set X equal to "row i" and column 1
    Y = A(i+1, 1); %this i don't know what to do.. I want this to be the row 
                  %directly below i so if i is row 1, then I want this to be 
                  %row 2
    bsxfun(@minus, X, Y)
end
```

I feel like this should be simple but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I appreciate all feedback! If my question needs more clarification, please let me know! :)

Comment: You're not getting *any* output? You should be getting an error message that should help you figure out one of your problems.

Comment: yeah it's rlly weird... I'm not sure why I don't receive any output.

Comment: Okay, the first error is that you don't initialize `i`. By default, `i` is the [imaginary unit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html). For this reason, using `i` as a loop variable is frowned upon in MATLAB.

Comment: You don’t initialize `i`, and you don’t increment it. You also don’t need `bsxfun`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo okay, so if I don't use i, then what do i use for the loop?

Comment: It’s better to choose a different name, but you can use `i` if you really want to. That is not the problem. But it is the reason you are not getting an error message. Your problem is that you need to initialize it (`i = 1`) before the loop, and increment it inside the loop (`i = i + 1`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's interesting. Octave gives an error: `error: a(0+1i,_): subscripts must be real (forgot to initialize i or j?)`

Comment: @beaker: I suspect that MATLAB considers `i <= B` to be false, so it skips the loop altogether.

Comment: Your next problem is that `i` goes all the way up to `B`, the last index, but you ask for `B+1`, which is one past the last element.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, it appears MATLAB considers `i` to be less than any positive real number.

Comment: Whereas Octave thinks `i > 1` but `i < (1+eps)`. :-/

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has a built-in function, `diff`, that does what you want:

```
>> A = [4; 6; 7; 11; 12; 17; 22; 25];
>> diff(A)

ans =

     2
     1
     4
     1
     5
     5
     3
```

You could also get the same result using array slicing:

```
>> A(2:end) - A(1:end-1)
```